# LinqToSql - avoiding excessive queries to the database

Tags: .net, performance, linq-to-sql

This scenario comes up often, now that I use LinkToSql and the classes it creates.

Classic scenario - two tables:

**Member**
ID
Name
...

**Membership**
ID
MemberID (foreign key)
Start (datetime)
Expiration (datetime)
...

An active membership would be one where now is between start and expiration.

To find out if a user has an active membership, I have created this partial class to extend on the LinkToSql-generated Member-class:

```
Partial Public Class Member
    Public ReadOnly Property HasActiveMembership() As Boolean
        Get
            Dim activeMembershipCount As Integer = (From m In Me.Memberships _
                                Where m.MemberId = Me.MemberId _
                                And m.StartDate < Now And m.ExpirationDate > Now() _
                                Select m).Count

            If activeMembershipCount > 0 Then Return True Else Return False

        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

This works great for one member, but when I want to list 700 members and if they have active membership or not, it makes 700+ calls to the database.

How should I change my model/classes?

I could create a query just for lists, where make the entire thing into one query, which is pretty straightforward, but I would like to avoid that, if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options; for example, you could use [`DataLoadOptions.LoadWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx) or [`DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548919.aspx) to fetch the data eagerly - however, the optimal approach depends on how you are using it.

For example, you could write a "users with active membership" query (either in LINQ using `Any`, or with a SPROC/UDF). That would then be 1 round trip, but is arguably less object-centric (and more query centric). Which might be fine...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have an association defined, perhaps due to a FK relationship between the tables. That being the case, you can simply extend your membership query using a where clause using the entity reference already defined on the class.

C# example:

```
var query = db.Members.Where( m => m.Memberships
                                    .Any( ms => ms.StartDate > now
                                                && ms.ExpirationDate < now ));
```

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to show all members - and a true/false if they actually have an active membership. Not just the members with an actual active membership. :)

Comment: Look at @Marc's answer with respect to the DataLoadOptions.  If the data isn't lazily loaded, your query against Memberships won't go back against the database -- it will be LinqToObjects.  You should probably use Any() instead of calculating the count, too.  I would expect in LinqToObjects it will short circuit after the first one is found.  Count would need to examine all of them.  Probably a small performance benefit, but its the right method to use.

Comment: Better than short circuit; in many cases it'll use EXISTS / COUNT / TOP 1 etc (I can't remember which), rather than actually fetch all of them

Comment: @Marc -- that would be true if they hadn't been loaded yet.  Once they're in memory, I would think that it would actually have to look at each one or at least until it found one.